# Multi Client TCP server C++ issue

Tags: c++, windows, networking, tcp, network-programming

I have made Mutlti-Client sever that can receive and send messages to the sever and the sever can send back the messages to clients but the problem I'm having is client A will not be able to receive the message from client B unless Client A sends a message I want the clients to receive messages anytime I also want to be to type commands on the sever without stopping the flow of sending to clients and receiving message from clients

I have tried moving the `std::getline(std::cin, ClientInput);` to different place in the code so clients could be able to see message but I have notice in the code the while loop does not continue because of it is there a way to get user input with out stopping the loop so can send and receive messages

This the Client code

````
int Client::OnCreate()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    char sendbuf[] = "this is a test";
    std::vector<SOCKET> ConnectedUser;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;

    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    std::string ClientInput;

    std::cout << "please send a message " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, ClientInput);

    do {
        if (ClientInput.size() > 0)
        {
            //send user input to sever 
            iResult = send(ConnectSocket, ClientInput.c_str(), ClientInput.size(), 0);

            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                system("pause");
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);

            if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                //receive user input from sever 
                int iUserResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
                if (iUserResult > 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "Client receive this message from sever \t" << std::string(recvbuf, 0, iResult) << std::endl;
                    printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iUserResult);
                }

            }

            //will disconnect from the sever
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                system("pause");

            }
            //will disconnect from the sever if user types in logoff
            if (ClientInput == "logoff")
            {
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                printf("Connection closing goodbye sever\n");
                system("pause");

            }
            //close connection if the no user input 
            if (iResult == 0) {
                printf("Connection closed\n");
                iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
            }

        }

        std::getline(std::cin, ClientInput);
    } while (ClientInput.size() > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);

    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}```
````

This is the sever code

````
std::vector<SOCKET> ConnectedUser;
std::vector<int> UserInt;
unsigned __stdcall ClientSession(void *data)
{
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

        int recvbufleng = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
        int iResult;
        int iSendResult;

        SOCKET ClientSocket = (SOCKET)data;

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL, hints;
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        do
        {   
            iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbufleng, 0);
            ///iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(Player), 0);
            std::cout << iResult << std::endl;

            if (iResult > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < ConnectedUser.size(); i++) {
                    std::cout << "send message to "<< ConnectedUser[i] << std::endl;
                    //iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
                    iSendResult = send(ConnectedUser[i], recvbuf, iResult, 0);
                    //ConnectedUser.clear();
                    //iSendResult = sendto(ConnectedUser[i], recvbuf, iResult, 0, (sockaddr*)&hints, sizeof(hints));

                }

                std::cout << "ClientSocket" << ClientSocket << std::endl;

                if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    printf("send failed with error: %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
                    closesocket(ClientSocket);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 1;
                }
                printf("Received Message %.*s\n", iResult, recvbuf);
            }
            else if (iResult == 0)
            {
                printf("connection closing.... \n");
                std::cout << "user logged off" << ClientSocket << std::endl;                
            }
            else
            {
                printf("recv failed with error: %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }       
        } while (iResult > 0);

        iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("shutdown failed with error: %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        closesocket(ClientSocket);
}

int Sever::OnCreate()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

        int iResult;
        SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        //send to 
        char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
        int recvbufleng = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

        int iSendResult;

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL, hints;
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));

        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

        //create the winsocket
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n, iResult");

            return 1;

        }
        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, int(result->ai_addrlen));

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("bind failed with error: %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("Listen failed with error: %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Create the master file descriptor set and zero it
        fd_set master;
        FD_ZERO(&master);

        FD_SET(ListenSocket, &master);

        fd_set copy = master;
        int socketCount = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        std::cout << " socketCount "<< socketCount << std::endl;

        //// Send an initial buffer
        //if (socketCount == 0) {
        //  std::string SeverInput;
        //  std::cout << "input Server command" << std::endl;
        //  std::getline(std::cin, SeverInput);
        //  
        //  if (SeverInput == "exit")
        //  {
        //      closesocket(ClientSocket);
        //      WSACleanup();
        //      printf("Connection closing goodbye sever\n");
        //  }
        //}

        for (int i = 0; i < socketCount; i++)
        {
            SOCKET sock = copy.fd_array[i];

            if (sock == ListenSocket)
            {
                //// Accept a new connection
                while ((ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL))) {
                    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                        printf("Accept failed with error: %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
                        closesocket(ListenSocket);
                        WSACleanup();
                        return 1;
                    }               

                /*  Messtotal.push_back(ClientSocket + "\n");*/


                    // Add the new connection to the list of connected clients
                    FD_SET(ClientSocket, &master);

                    ConnectedUser.push_back(ClientSocket);

                    std::cout << "client:" << ClientSocket <<" has arrived on sever" <<std::endl;


                    // Create a new thread for the accepted client (also pass the accepted client socket).
                    unsigned threadID;
                    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &ClientSession, (void*)ClientSocket, 0, &threadID);
                }
            }

        }

        WSACleanup();
        printf("Server shutting down ");
        return 0;
```}
````

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem: What kind of messages do you expect coming from Cilent B when the latter hasn't sent any messages yet?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the std::getline(std::cin, ClientInput) anywhere within loop in client code will not help you becase getline() is a blocking call. In this case you should use threads in client code.

You need to create a new thread in client code with while loop. In this thread you will incoming messages from another client.

Main thread in client code will handle user input from getline() and sending messages via send function within while loop.

For example in your client code you can create thread like this :

```
m_hTrhead = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)processMessage, (LPVOID)ConnectSocket, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);

if (m_hTrhead == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to create thread for receiving messages , error code : %ld \n", GetLastError());
    return false;
}
```

And thread will will process messages in function processMessage like this :

```
DWORD WINAPI Socket::processMessage(LPVOID lpParam)
 {
      SOCKET ConnectSocket= reinterpret_cast <SOCKET>(lpParam);
      while (WSAGetLastError() != WSAECONNRESET)
      {
         int iUserResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
         if (iUserResult > 0)
         {
           std::cout << "Client receive this message from sever \t" << std::string(recvbuf, 0, iResult) << std::endl;
         printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iUserResult);
         }
    }
 }
```

Be aware that non- blocking sockets exists also (So thread will not stop at recv or send function). Function names for non-blocking socket are the same but you must set the socket itself to non-blocking.

```
u_long mode = 1;  // enable non-blocking socket
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &mode);
```

You can read about this more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-ioctlsocket)